# Tools on Okteta not working

Tags: kde

I have opened a (binary) file with the `okteta` hex editor in Ubuntu 20.04. However, most of the **Tools** are disabled. For example:

- The **Terminal** tool opens a completely empty tab.
- The **Checksum** tool has a dropdown list box and I am able to select an **Algorithm**, however the **Calculate** button is disabled (greyed out).
- The **Charset Conversion** tool has all its fields disabled.
- The **Strings** tool has all its buttons disabled.
- The **Statistics** tool has its **Build** button disabled.

The version of Okteta is 0.26.3. Do I need to install something extra?

Comment: I tried Okteta in lubuntu 18.04 with all dependencies installed and I had all of your problems except the second one and the last one. But when I tried it in Kubuntu 20.04 , all of the features worked correctly.  After searching through the [Okteta source code](https://github.com/KDE/okteta/blob/master/libs/kasten/controllers/document/terminal/terminalview.cpp#L59) , I found that it makes use of [KServiceTypeTrade](https://api.kde.org/frameworks/kservice/html/classKServiceTypeTrader.html#ac504a7e11c04d9d70681b99f2463243d) to open the terminal which requires KDE infrastructure.

Comment: I think it's just better integrated with KDE desktop that any other DE. That example was just for the terminal emulator. But the same situation might exist for other extensions as well.It's very difficult to figure out which package is needed to make it work correctly. I personally had installed KDE connect with all dependencies in linux mint 19.2 a few month ago but that didn't work even I had installed the kubuntu-desktop package. So I think the solution is to either use another hex viewer or just use  Kubuntu or any other KDE-based distro.

Comment: But still you have an option which is to clone into the [repository](https://github.com/KDE/okteta) , and try compiling the project . After running "cmake ." it will scan your system for required modules. If it cannot find some of them , it would tell you which one is missing.So I think it's a good place to start.